# how do i check for trail whitespace on python?

Tags: python, string, whitespace, syntax-checking

I am trying to write a function to check for trail whitespace, but not to remove the spaces. but i have no idea of how to do that. can somebody teach me?

thank you

Answer (score 5):

Using [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
>>> 'with trailing space  '.endswith(' ')
True
>>> 'without trailing space'.endswith(' ')
False
```